# C# cannot access the file, because it used by other process

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, streamwriter, export-to-csv

I have the code that transfers SQL into CSV :

```
public void CreateCSVFile(DataTable dt, string strFilePath, bool Is_Ordre, int TypeDonne)
{

    //FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Create);
    // FileStream fs = File.Create(strFilePath);

    // Create the CSV file to which grid data will be exported.
    //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false))
    {
        // First we will write the headers.
        //DataTable dt = m_dsProducts.Tables[0];
        int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
        {
            sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
            if (i < iColCount - 1)
            {
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }
        if (Is_Ordre) sw.Write(", TYP_DONNE");

        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

        // Now write all the rows.
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
            {
                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                {
                    sw.Write("\'" + dr[i].ToString().Replace("'", " ").Replace(",", ".") + "\'");
                }
                else
                {
                    sw.Write("\' \'");
                }
                if (i < iColCount - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
            }
            if (Is_Ordre) sw.Write(", \'" + TypeDonne + "\'");
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        }                
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
    }
        //fs.Close();

}
```

After that I send the CSV file via email:

```
Attachment data_OD = new Attachment(LeSource, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
Attachment data_LV = new Attachment(LeSource_LV, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
oEmail.SendingEmail(ClientID,  data_OD, data_LV);

public void SendingEmail(string CodeClient, Attachment dataOD, Attachment dataLV)
{
    try
    {
        Pers_Conf oConf = LeConf.Get_Config(CodeClient);

        MailMessage omail = new MailMessage();
        var oSmtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx"),
            EnableSsl = true
        };

        omail.From = new MailAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com");               
        omail.To.Add(oConf.EmailAddr);
        omail.Subject = "xxxxxx_" + CodeClient;
        omail.Body = CodeClient;

        omail.Attachments.Add(dataOD);
        omail.Attachments.Add(dataLV);

        oSmtp.Send(omail);
    }
    catch (Exception excThrown)
    {
        throw excThrown;
    }
```

it seems that `StreamWriter` does not properly close the file, I already try with this :

```
    Try
    {
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
    }
    Catch
    {
    }
    Finaly
    {
     sw.Flush();
     sw.Close();
     sw.Dispose();
}
```

but in the `finally` block it does not recognize `sw`.

Any idea ?

PS: this line of code throws an exception that tell that the file is being use by other process

```
 using (var sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false))
```

is not closing because of `StreamWriter` not properly close or it is because send email is using this file ?

Comment: Could you be more specific on which line you get the exception? On the initial using ?

Comment: This happens on the first time the program access this function, or the whole process (build, send) is repeated with the same file name more than one time?

Comment: it happen on the second time the programm acess this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you enter in this code more than one time.
In either case you need to call the `MailMsg.Dispose()` of the `MailMessage` class. 
Otherwise, it will hold the attachment resulting in a file locked the next time you try to write in it.

Try to use the `using` statement also on the MailMessage

```
        try 
        { 
            Pers_Conf oConf = LeConf.Get_Config(CodeClient); 

            using(MailMessage omail = new MailMessage())
            {
                .....
                oSmtp.Send(omail); 
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception excThrown) 
        { 
            throw excThrown; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `StreamWriter` is declared out of scope, try this instead:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false))
{
}
```

This will add the `try` and `finally` code for you at compile time.  Alternatively, if you want to specify the `try` blocks yourself do this:

```
StreamWriter sw;

try
{
    sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
    sw.Dispose();        
}
```

This will give it scope to the `finally`.

**EDIT**

You could try adding `using` blocks to your file stream to create your file, and then write to this stream with `StreamWriter` as you're kind of already doing, as Darin points out.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        // write your content

        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }

    fs.Close();
}
```

If you're creating your file using `File.Create` as it seems in your code (but it's commented out) then you're not closing your `FileStream` so this may be a factor.

Comment: That's what he currently has. Look at his code once again, inside the `CreateCSVFile` method.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: yeah that was a bit of lazy reading, I only caught the last part assuming that was his question.

Answer (score 0):

The StreamWriter will be out of scope. If you refractor to the following...

```
StreamWriter sw;
try
{
   sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
}
Catch
{

}
finally
{
 sw.Flush();
 sw.Close();
 sw.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last block of code `sw` is not recognized because it is out of scope.

Please try this:

```
 StreamWriter sw;

 try
 {
    sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
 }
 catch
 {
    // Never do an empty catch BTW!    
 }
 finally
 {
   if (sw != null)
   {
     sw.Flush();
     sw.Close();
     sw.Dispose();
   }
}
```

or better yet, use a using statement:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false))
{
    // Just do your thing, at the end sw will be cleaned up for you :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like your first attemopt was reasonable (in summary below)

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false)) 
{ 
    sw.Flush();  
    sw.Close();  
    sw.Dispose();  
}
```

Though sw..Dispose() not needed as it is in a using{} block.

So what exactly was the problem you were seeing?

Ok, I have just seen your edit.  Are you sure it is not something else locking the file, possibly the Attachment.  I cannot see what scope this is being declared in, but is it possible that it is hanging on to the file?  If you want to check what is locking it you can use ProcessMonitor...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx